# Thread Local Store and Task Local Store

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

What is the difference between Thread Local Store and Task Local Store ? Why it is different since the underlying constructs relaying on thread in general.

Comment: Where did you hear about “Task Local Store”? When I [google that term](https://www.google.cz/search?q="Task+Local+Store"), this question is the first result.

Comment: @svick, I recently happen to read a book called "Parallel Programming with Microsoft.NET (Design Patterns for Decomposition and Coordination on Multicore Architectures)" published under microsoft Pattern and Practice. Specifically on 75th page where they are refering about Thread local state/store and Task local state/store. I haven't got it properly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no concept of “Task Local Store”. The part of the book you mentioned talks about `Parallel.ForEach()` (and `For()`). These methods have overloads with `localInit` and `localFinally` delegates, and the objects these delegates work with can be though of as “task-local”.

I think the main differences between thread-local and task-local here is that with task-local, you can be sure that subsequent code won't see values you forgot to clean up, even if that code runs on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is this, I'm not sure if it is relevant.

AsyncLocal< T > .... class to persist local data across threads in async

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx